# SQL query without foreign key in other table

Tags: mysql

i have problem with MySQL query, I have two tables - offers and bids:

```
offers                       bids

id status                  id offer_id user_id
1  new                     1     1        1
2  new                     2     1        2
3  rejected                3     2        1    
4  accepted                4     4        4
5  new                     5     5        2
6  new                     6     6        3
7  new                     7     7        1
```

Assuming that user_id = 2, I need all offers (from table offers)for this user_id which have status ="new", but without these offers which that user has bid (without offer 1 and offer 5)

I tried with "not exists" but without much success. Like:

```
SELECT distinct o.*
FROM offers o 
LEFT JOIN bids AS b 
ON o.id = b.offer_id
WHERE o.status = "new" AND (b.user_id!=2 
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  offers off WHERE b.offer_id = off.id))
```

And similiar ( i can get result when there is no other users that bid same offer),
but I cant get what I need.

EDIT:

As output in this case I need offers with IDs:

2 6 7      (offers 3 and 4 are not "new" and for offers 1 and 5 that user has already bids)

Comment: so for user ID 1, why should we return offer 7 and not offer 1? What's the criteria? Why can't we return 1, and not return 7, instead?

Comment: @ADyson For id 1, 5 & 6 should displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT distinct o.*
FROM offers o
WHERE o.status = "new" AND
      o.id not in (select offer_id from bids where user_id = 2);
```

If you want  to display for all the users then try following query:

```
SELECT distinct o.*
    FROM offers o 
    Inner JOIN bids AS b 
    ON o.id = b.offer_id
    WHERE o.status = "new" AND              
Group by b.user_id
having o.id not in (select offer_id from bids b1 where b1.user_id = b.user_id);
```

Comment: Always glad to help !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a join here. Its very simple

- Select offers where status is `new`
- Exclude those offers where `user = 2` has bid

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM offers o
WHERE o.`status` = 'new' AND
    o.id NOT IN (SELECT offer_id from bids b WHERE b.user_id = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct o.*
FROM offers o 
JOIN bids  b 
ON o.id = b.offer_id
WHERE o.status = "new" 
     AND (o.id not in (select distinct(offer_id) from bids bi where bi.user_id=2 ))
```